# Как правильно сохранять TODO list в LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript

Нужен совет как правильно сохранить список дел в LocalStorage.
У меня есть масив, при добавлении нового дела, буду записывать его innerHTML и свойство check, в объект, потом этом объект пушить в масив. В результате получиться масив с объектами (делами). Который я уже спокойно буду кидать в LocalStorage. Но у меня проблема, при удалении дела, нужно удалять и его объект в масиве, и я не очень понимаю как это реализовать. Может есть какие-то другие варианты. Заранее благодарю!
P.s. как вариант в LS можно сохранить целый container с делами. К примеру:

```
`localStorage.setItem("todos", container.innerHTML);`
```

Насколько это уместно?

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` в песке отключен, поэтому для полного тестирования можно посетить [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MoloF/87ea6ru5/77/)

Не знаю насколько качественно и понятно, но делал в первый раз подобное.

Сначала думал будет не тривиальная и довольно простая задача, но потом углубился в `Proxy` и небольшое взаимодействие и кода так прибавилось.

Здесь есть один важный аспект - это `Proxy`.

Я его использовал только для того, чтобы следить за состоянием массива и проверять, не был ли он изменен.

После чего я запускал рендер и сохранял изменения.

Так же добавил смену состояния через `чекбокс`, удаление и добавление с помощью `prompt`.

*Ответ оставляю общим, мне кажется я там перебрал с кодом и можно было сделать легче но я не знаю как (или просто лень).*

*(изначально все было на функциях и я перенес на классы, ибо обилие функций кровоточило глаза)*

```js
class Todo {
 constructor() {
  this.list = document.querySelector('ul');

  const proxyHandle = {
   set: (target, property, value) =>
    this.proxySetHandle(target, property, value),
  };
 
  this.tasks = this.getTasks();
  this.proxyTasks = new Proxy(this.tasks, proxyHandle);
  
  this.renderTask();
  
  const button = document.querySelector('button');
  button.onclick = () => this.createTask();
 }
 
 taskSchema(status, name) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('li');
  wrapper.innerHTML = (`
   <input type="checkbox" ${status ? 'checked' : null}>
   <span>${name}</span>
   <i>x</i>
  `);
  return wrapper;
 }
 
 taskChangeStatus(index, status) {} 
 
 getTasks() {
  return localStorage.getItem('tasks')
   ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'))
   : []
 }
 saveTasks() {
  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(this.tasks));
 }
 createTask() {
  const name = prompt('Введите название задания');
  if (name.length <= 0 || name.length > 100) return;
  this.proxyTasks.push({
   status: false,
   name
  });
 }
 
 changeTaskStatus(index, status) {
  this.proxyTasks[index].status = status;
  this.saveTasks();
 }
 removeTask(index) {
  this.proxyTasks.splice(index, 1);
 }
 
 renderTask() {
  this.list.innerHTML = '';
  this.tasks.forEach(task => {
   const schema = this.taskSchema(
    task.status,
    task.name
   );
   
   this.list.appendChild(schema);
  });
  
  const tasks = this.list.querySelectorAll('li');
  
  tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
   const status = task.querySelector('input');
   const remove = task.querySelector('i');
   
   status.onchange = (e) =>
    this.changeTaskStatus(index, e.target.checked);
   
   remove.onclick = () => this.removeTask(index);
  });
 }
 
 proxySetHandle(target, property, value) {
  target[property] = value;
  this.saveTasks();
  this.renderTask();
  return true;
 }
}

new Todo();
```

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

ul li input:checked + span {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}
ul li i {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Добавить задание</button>
<ul></ul>
```